# How to fix nextjs cloudfront static assets respond with 403?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-s3, amazon-cloudfront, serverless-framework, serverless

I am trying to deploy my website to aws with cloudfront and route53. The site is deployed and running on https://higgle.io
However the assets are not loading, for the images are throwing 403. How do I fix it?
I am using serverless `serverless-next.js`. And I was following one of their blog post to set it up.
So far I added which has `serverless.yml` on the route level.

```
higgle:
 component: serverless-next.js
```

and my next.config.js looks like

```
module.exports = {
  target: 'serverless',
  webpack: (config) => {
    config.module.rules.push({
      test: /\.svg$/,
      use: ['@svgr/webpack'],
    });
    return config
  }
}
```

While the folder structrs looks like

```
-root
  -.next
  -pages
    -_document.js
    -index.js
  -public
    -static
      -favicon.ico
  -next.config.js
  -package.json
  -serverless.yml
```

Any idea how to fix this?
Thanks

Comment: Did you ever figure this out, I've got 1 fricken css file that's giving 403, just trying to figure out why.

Comment: My issue was images, and it was in `static` folder inside the `public` folder, I renamed the  `static` to `images` it started working.
Coming to your css issue, you have added it? or Nextjs adding it?

Comment: Yeah I actually came across that, I just moved it to the public/ folder and works great now.

Comment: Happy that it worked 

Answer (score 1):

S3 is returning a 403 because your items are private.

1. Change your S3 items to public. Check that they are accessible via your S3 static hosting address.
2. Step 1 will fix any static resources. If you are running a single page application, you will also need to return your index page when a 404 is returned by S3. In CloudFront, go to error pages, create a custom error response, choose 404 response, choose the option to customize the response, make the response code 200 and the response page path your index page.

Your bucket policy should be:

```
{
"Version": "2012-10-17",
"Id": "Policy1517754859350",
"Statement": [
    {
        "Sid": "Stmt1517754856505",
        "Effect": "Allow",
        "Principal": "*",
        "Action": "s3:GetObject",
        "Resource": "arn:aws:s3:::YOUR-BUCKET-NAME/*"
    }
]
```

}

Comment: I made my whole s3 bucket public. :( I can able to see the files hitting download url. But not with the cloudfront. I guess there something I am missing which would enable these static files to the public or something.

Comment: I have updated the answer with the bucket policy you need. If that doesn't work, please update your answer with more information, including the actual error message you are getting and exact details of your bucket setup.

Comment: I changed the principle to "*", but still its not loading. `GET https://higgle.io/static/Menu_Temp.png 404` this is what the error is.
Actually I didnt create the bucket its automatically created by serverless. so tell me what kind of info you need, I will provide all of them.

Comment: Your s3 bucket needs to be setup for website hosting, have you done that?
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonS3/latest/dev/WebsiteHosting.html

Comment: You do not need to change the policy like this to get access to the items within the instance. The norm is to use origin access identities, and it will handle the policy part for you as well. 

Also cloudfront will throw a 403 error if it doesn't find the file within the bucket, whether that be because it doesn't exist or that the path to the file isn't exact. It must include the .html suffix which causes some errors with how some routers are configured. 

Try connecting to the instance with an origin access identity, and never make your bucket public, that gives too many security concerns

Comment: What security concerns, exactly? I'm all for security. If you're hosting a website, having a public S3 bucket is the norm. Don't put private stuff in a website bucket, its as simple as that.